# replace XML variable in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I replace the variable value of xml in sql? I need to change the values of ID and Text.

**Sample XML**

```
<Values>
   <ValueList>
      <Entry key="Num" type="Values">
         <value ID="1" Text="One" />
      </Entry>
      <Entry key="Name" type="Values">
         <value ID="2" Text="two" />
      </Entry>
   </ValueList>
</Values>
```

Comment: <Values> <ValueList> <Entry key="Num" type="Values"> <value ID="1" Text="One" /> </Entry> <Entry key="Name" type="Values"> <value ID="2" Text="two" /> </Entry> </ValueList> </Values>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modified the ID value like following. Here I am updating ID="1" to "111", similarly you can change the text for a specific text using `modify`.

```
DECLARE @XML XML
SET @XML= '<Values> <ValueList> <Entry key="Num" type="Values"> <value ID="1" Text="One" /> </Entry> <Entry key="Name" type="Values"> <value ID="2" Text="two" /> </Entry> </ValueList> </Values>'
SET @XML.modify('replace value of (Values/ValueList/Entry/value[@ID eq ("1")]/@ID)[1] with ("1111")')
select @XML
```

If you want to use variables, it can be achieved like following.

```
DECLARE @XML XML
Declare @IDTOReplace VARCHAR(5)='1'
DECLARE @IDWithReplace VARCHAR(5) = '111'
SET @XML= '<Values> <ValueList> <Entry key="Num" type="Values"> <value ID="1" Text="One" /> </Entry> <Entry key="Name" type="Values"> <value ID="2" Text="two" /> </Entry> </ValueList> </Values>'
SET @XML.modify('replace value of (Values/ValueList/Entry/value[@ID eq sql:variable("@IDTOReplace")]/@ID)[1] with sql:variable("@IDWithReplace")')
select @XML
```

If you want to change the Text based on some Id, it can be achieved like following.

```
DECLARE @XML XML
Declare @IDTOReplace VARCHAR(5)='1'
DECLARE @TextToReplace VARCHAR(100) = 'NewText'
SET @XML= '<Values> <ValueList> <Entry key="Num" type="Values"> <value ID="1" Text="One" /> </Entry> <Entry key="Name" type="Values"> <value ID="2" Text="two" /> </Entry> </ValueList> </Values>'
SET @XML.modify('replace value of (Values/ValueList/Entry/value[@ID eq sql:variable("@IDTOReplace")]/@Text)[1] with sql:variable("@TextToReplace")')
select @XML
```

Comment: Which id is not changing?

Comment: Check this example here http://rextester.com/HDTMM80792

Comment: If we want to change ID and Text at a time, is it possible?

Comment: You need to do like SET @XML.modify('...'), @XML.modify('...')